# sqlite - Multiple records referenced to single row

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, rows

I created a "tasks" program (python3.6) which has the following sqlite DB structure:

```
date, time, project, task, owner, comment
```

Each row represents a task and its working fine.  Now I want users to press the "add" button, a new comment field appears, filled out and saved. The new comment should be "tagged?" to the row of the original task so it can be shown to the user later.

The user should be able to add as many comment fields as they want over the course of the task.

It would end up looking something like this:

```
[row1] date, time, project, task, owner, comment, comment, comment, comment, comment
[row2] date, time, project, task, owner, comment, comment, comment
```

What is the best way to set the tables up within Sqlite? How do I link these extra comments to the same row when I dont know what the max number of comments will be?  Not even sure what to search on this.

TIA

Comment: You should have 2 tables : one for tasks and one for comment (this should contains the reference id of the task)

Comment: Thanks, that helps, got it working like you suggested.